# From within a xslt, can you output the entire XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

Inside my XSLT that is transforming a order XML, I want to dump the entire XML I am currently working with. How can I do this?

I am weaving some HTML based on XML, and want to dump the entire XML into a textarea.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly, that you want to produce a `<textarea>` element with your XSL stylesheet, and put the content of the XML inside of that element?

Answer (score 10):

**Probably the shortest ... :)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: do you need the method=xml attribute in the output?

Comment: omit-xml-declaration="yes" is going to omit the xml tags? i want them! :)

Comment: @Blankman: The "xml" method is the default, you may adjust the `<xsl:output>` instruction according to your taste.

Comment: Hmm..it seems to be showing up encoded in the email, not sure if its the xml processing or something else doing it.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to produce a `<textarea>` element, and dump everything *into* that element?

Then you can use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <textarea>
         <xsl:copy-of select="/" />     
      </textarea>
   </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Be careful:** The output won't be escaped!

Or put the `<xsl:copy-of>` wherever you produce the textarea.

<sub>Small note, if you have to work on really large XML files: If you call the copy-of from a template that matches somewhere deeper in the hierarchy, this can slow down the xslt processor, because it must "jump" outside of the local node. So, the xslt processor can't use certain optimizations.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```